# How to Restore Chatter Files?

Tags: chatter, files

I have exported all the Files from the Salesforce and I have also created the Developer Sandbox. Now I want to upload it to the Sandbox.
Now my question is How can I upload the Chatter Files, I don't want to do it manually. Is there any other way through Data Loader or another tool?

Please Guide

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

Chatter Files are represented on Salesforce by ContentVersion standard object.
So, if you use dataloader you might extract chatter files from one organization and then insert them into your target organization.